# CustomFunction has "Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a large script that controls my Spreadsheet file. Within that script, I would like to have some custom functions, but when I try adding some, I get a "Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context (line 1)".

I've isolated the code to find the problem, but want to keep line 1 for all the other code in my script that uses it.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

/**
 * Multiplies the input value by 2.
 *
 * @param {number} input The value to multiply.
 * @return The input multiplied by 2.
 * @customfunction
 */
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```

Comment: I tried the same thing your suggesting caused and error and I received no errors.  It's kind of a useless thing to do outside of a function body.  Note, there are situations where a UI cannot exist like opening a spreadsheet by Id because in that situation there is no user and without a user there is no need for a user interface.  Also you can't call the ui from a custom function.

Comment: You might  to take a close look at [Guide Line for Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#guidelines_for_custom_functions)

Comment: Try enclosing line 1 in a `try{}catch{}`

Answer (score -1):

You **cannot** call the ui from a custom function **but** you can move the `var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();` inside each function that you want it to use the actual ui.

You can read more about Custom Functions in Google Apps Script [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).